# sed replacing tex short-hand $$ with latex short-hand \( \)

Tags: bash, sed, latex

I currently have a problem when editing my `manuscript.tex` files. So far I have always used the text short-hand $$; however, something comes up and it requires me to replace all $...$ by `\( \)`.

I think "sed" with replacement operation should be a right tool for the task. However, I am not good or familiar with "sed" and regular expression. Therefore, I need hints and helps for doing this.

Supposed the input file is named as `manuscript.tex`. I need "sed" to replace `$ e=mc^2 $` with `\( e=mc^2 \)`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is never a newline between the dollar signs, you can try something like

```
sed -e 's/\$\([^$]\+\)\$/\\(\1\\)/g' manuscript.tex > manuscript2.tex
```

Comment: Hi @choroba, thanks for the correct solution. Just try to explain what I understand about your line of regular  expression, please correct me if I am wrong. The pattern for sed replacement is 's/pattern1/pattern2/g'. Pattern 1 here is \$\([^$]\+\)\$ and pattern 2 is \\(\1\\). In patter 1, there are two   \$ for open and close math environment in latex; [^$]\+ is for capturing from the begin to the end of strings between \$. In pattern 2, \\( and \\) are two replacements. What I don't understand are \( \) parts in the pattern 1 and \1 in the pattern 2. Why do you  need those symbols ?

Comment: @user24265: The `\(...\)` remebers the substring to be later inserted with `\1`. Generally, `\n` corresponds to the n-th capturing `\(`.

Answer (score 1):

Other way using sed

`sed -re 's/(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)/\\(\2\\)/g' temp.txt`